# Backbone, after chaging url in my collection, fetch is looping.

Tags: loops, backbone.js, collections, fetch

I'm pretty new with Backbone and I'm struggling with Backbone.Collection : 
I have a list of products in different categories (shoes, shirts, pants, ...). The idea is when an user clicks on a category, I'm updating URL in my Collection (ex : datas/shoes.json becomes datas/shirts.json) and do a collection.fetch() in order to render my new list.

It's actually working but I don't know why it's **continually triggering** "add", "remove" events. This is my code, let me know if you see something strange :

```
define([ 
    "backbone",
],

function(Backbone) 
{
    var ProductsView = Backbone.View.extend({

        el: "#products",

        initialize:function(){

            _.bindAll(this,"addItem","removeAll");
            this.populate();
        }, 

        populate:function(){

            this.collection = new ProductCollection();    
            this.listenTo(this.collection, 'add', this.addItem);
            this.listenTo(this.collection, 'remove', this.removeAll);    
            this.collection.fetch();
        },

        addItem(todo){

            var view = new ProductItemView({model: todo});
            this.$el.append(view.render().el);
        },

        removeAll:function(){

            this.$el.children().remove();
            this.collection.url = "datas/shoes.json";
            this.collection.fetch();
        },
    });

    return ProductsView;
});
```

This is my collection

```
define([ 
    "backbone",
    "models/modules/products/ProductModel"
], 

function(Backbone, ProductModel) 
{
    var ProductsCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({

        model : ProductModel,
        url : "datas/shirts.json",

        parse: function(response){
            return response.products;
        },
    });

    return ProductsCollection;
});
```

**Thanks for your help** guys !!
Let me know if it's not clear, I'll try to clarify that.

Comment: You will get a remove event for each element that is not in the collection after the fetch, but you have binded the remove event to `removeAll` which will do another fetch. That might be the cause for the constant events.

Answer (score 0):

it's definitely helpful to give up, go to bed, in order to take a step back. 
So I've read the documentation and found **reset** method :

```
remove:function(todo){
    this.$el.children().remove();
    this.collection.reset();
    this.collection.url = "datas/shoes.json";
    this.collection.fetch();
},
```